# MDX MEMBER causing NON EMPTY to not filter

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm using an MDX query to pull information to support a set of reports.  A high degree of detail is required for the reports so they take some time to generate.  To speed up the access time we pull the data we need and store it in a flat Oracle table and then connect to the table in Excel.  This makes the reports refresh in seconds instead of minutes.

Previously the MDX was generated and run by department for 100 departments and then for a number of other filters.  All this was done in VB.Net.  The requirements for filters have grown to the point where this method is not sustainable (and probably isn't the best approach regardless).

I've built the entire dataset into one MDX query that works perfectly.  One of my sets that I cross join includes members from three different levels of hierarchy, it looks like this:

```
(
Descendants([Merch].[Merch CHQ].[All], 2),
Descendants([Merch].[Merch CHQ].[All], 3),
[Merch].[Merch CHQ].[Department].&[1].Children
)
```

The problem for me is in our hierarchy (which I can't change), each group (first item) and each department (second item) have the same structure to their naming, ie 15-DeptName and it's confusing to work with.

To address it I added a member:

```
MEMBER
[Measures].[Merch Level] AS
(
[Merch].[Merch CHQ].CurrentMember.Level.Name
)
```

Which returns what type the member is and it works perfectly.

The problem is that it updates for every member so none of the rows get filtered by NON BLANK, instead of 65k rows I have 130k rows which will hurt my access performance.

Can my query be altered to still filter out the non blanks short of using IIF to check each measurement for null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify Null for your member based on your main measure like:

```
MEMBER
[Measures].[Merch Level] AS
IIf(IsEmpty([Measures].[Normal Measure]),null,[Merch].[Merch CHQ].CurrentMember.Level.Name)
```

That way it will only generate when there is data. You can go further and add additional dimensions to the empty check if you need to get more precise.